# Regex for a n digit number that ends with a particular letter

Tags: regex, go, text-processing

How can I extract:

1. A string with n digits (say 10) that ends with a letter (say "A"), for example: 4024204455A
2. A 12-digit number, for example: 192345006905

using a regex, from multiple text files with Go (golang)?

Comment: How can I 1. get your attempts? 2. get the lang that you're currently running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match either 12 digits `[0-9]{12}` or 10 digits and an uppercase character `[0-9]{10}[A-Z]` using an or `|` in a non capturing group `(?:` for example:

[`^(?:[0-9]{12}|[0-9]{10}[A-Z])$`](https://regex101.com/r/UBigJ3/1)

Or match your values between word boundaries `\b`:

[`\b(?:[0-9]{12}|[0-9]{10}[A-Z])\b`](https://regex101.com/r/oFjvOu/1)

To match one or more digits OR 10 digits followed by an uppercase character your could use this regex with word boundaries or anchored `$^`:

[`\b(?:[0-9]+|[0-9]{10}[A-Z])\b`](https://regex101.com/r/pySvBr/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input = array();
$input[] = '123456789000A';
$input[] = '123456789012';
$input[] = '12345678901';

foreach($input as $i)
{
    preg_match("/^([0-9]+[a-z]{1}|[0-9]{12})$/i", $i, $m);
    print_r($m);
}
```

Output: First match, second match, third not match

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123456789000A
    [1] => 123456789000A
)
Array
(
    [0] => 123456789012
    [1] => 123456789012
)
Array
(
)
```

Comment: Why are you showing PHP code when the question is tagged Go?

Comment: @icza: Read the comment on the question: "How can I 1. get your attempts? 2. get the lang that you're currently running?" Check the revision history: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49252535/2. The go tag was added to the original question after this answer was posted.